# Highlight areas without overlapping Shapefies in QGIS 2.16

Tags: qgis, shapefile, clip, overlapping-features, intersect

[image: multiple shapefiles colored black with 50% transparency. As you can see there are areas with one, two, and even three overlapping shapefiles.]I have a dataset with several hundred shapefiles and need to ensure that there is at least double overlap throughout. I need a way to extract the areas without double overlap, or at least a way to color by number of overlapping shapefiles.

The image is of multiple shapefiles colored black with 50% transparency. As you can see there are areas with one, two, and even three overlapping shapefiles. With the 50% transparency, you can see the gaps with only single overlap, and I could manually delineate them, but I am looking for a way to do it automatically.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].  What do you mean by "double overlap"?  Could you please [edit] your question to include a description of your data, and perhaps a screenshot showing what you mean?

Comment: Thanks for the feeback Midavalo, let me know if this makes more sense.

Comment: This is a basic application of the Union operation. Merge them together, count the presence of data, and extract those with less than two sources.